# How to access the Form Tools from Other Classes

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and theres something i cant do and cant find from the internet about the problem i have.

I'm making a basic Rullet game for practice.

I want to make the Calculations in a separate Class for the sake of "Clean Coding".

But i cant manage to control things like radioButton, CheckBox, TextBox from the Calculation Class i made.

How can i access them?

For example i want to check if the Rulet number if Even or Odd from another class.

```
// form.cs

public static int ruletNumber;

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random ();
    ruletNumber = rnd.Next(0,37);
    Calculation.Calc();

}



//Calculation.cs
class Calculation
{
        public static void Calc()
        {
            // this is where i must see if the radioButton is Checked or Not, but it dosent see it from this Class...
            if (ruletNumber / 2 == 0 && rdbEven.Checked == true)
            {
                //some code...
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Pass parameters. Pass the ruletNumber and the checked state as parameters to the Calc method.

Comment: Define entity classes which is having properties for your calculations. From the form, manipulate the properties of the class according to checkbox clicks and others. Then Pass that object to the Calculation class to do the calculation from there. like  wise you can control the object information as you need.

Comment: is it impossible to control the radioButton in other classes? other then form.cs?

Comment: It *is* possible, however you shouldn´t do it - and you won´t need to do this. You should only pass the **values** from your form to your model, however the actual controls should not be accessable from it.

Comment: Ok, but now im just curious how you can do that?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass those parameters to your `Calc()` method like

```
ruletNumber = rnd.Next(0,37);
Calculation.Calc(ruletNumber, rdbEven.Checked);
```

In which case you will have to change the method signature in your class like below. Also, I believe your condition `ruletNumber / 2 == 0` should be `ruletNumber % 2 == 0` since you are trying to check whether it's odd/even number

```
class Calculation
{
        public static void Calc(int ruletNumber, bool radiostate)
        {
        if (ruletNumber % 2 == 0 && radiostate)
        {
            //some code...
        }
    }
```